# Windowsの再起動時に「tが再起動を妨げています」と表示されるのはなぜですか。

Tags: windows

Windowsのドライブのフォルダーに検索をかけていますが、tというアプリケーションが見つかりません。なぜ？

Comment: 隠しファイルになっていないですか？

Comment: @rookmot さん、正確さを期そうとして内容を削っているようですが、タイトルの「なぜ」と記事本文の「なぜ」がズレていて何が問題なのか何を知りたい/解決したいのか曖昧です。タイトルのなぜで「tが再起動を妨げています」と表示されるのは実際にそのプログラムが終了せず再起動を妨げているのでしょう。そして本文のなぜで「t」が見つからないのは sayuri さん回答の状況が当てはまりそうです。対象を見つけたいなら y_waiwai さん回答のタスクマネージャのプロセスのタブで、デフォルトでは表示されない「プロセス名」「コマンドライン」の欄を表示するようにすれば分かるかもしれません。より詳しくは[プロセス エクスプローラー v17.02](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)とか他のSysinternalsのツールで探せるかもしれません。

Answer (score 7):

ここは[プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のためのQ&Aサイト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)ですので、その観点で。

[The program “G” is preventing you from shutting down](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191030-00/?p=103036)や日本語解説記事 [「Windows 10」のシャットダウンを妨げる謎の「G」アプリ、マイクロソフトが説明](https://japan.zdnet.com/article/35145860/) があります。

Windowsには文字列を扱う型が２種類あります。

- ANSI（日本語においてはShift-JIS）
  １文字1バイトが基本であり、日本語文字などの非ASCII文字は2バイトとなる。
  例えば`ABC`なら `0x61 0x62 0x63 0x00` となり終端の`NUL`を加えて4バイトとなる。
- Unicode（厳密にはUTF-16）
  １文字2バイトが基本。ASCII文字であっても2バイトであり、その場合上位ビットは0となる。
  例えば`ABC`なら `0x61 0x00 0x62 0x00 0x63 0x00 0x00 0x00` となり8バイトとなる。

ここで、APIが文字列型を取り違えると、つまり、Unicode形式の`ABC`をANSI形式として解釈すると2バイト目の`0x00`で終端されて`A`という文字列になってしまいます。

記事では、Unicodeでの`GDI+ Hook Window`がANSIで解釈すると`G`になってしまうことが指摘されていますが、質問の状況においても同様で、`t`から始まる何らかの**ウィンドウタイトル**なのでしょう。
また、ここで表示されるのは実行ファイル名ではなくウィンドウタイトルですので、`t.exe`を探しても無意味です。（例えば実行ファイル名`notepad.exe`のウィンドウタイトルは`メモ帳`になります。）

Answer (score 2):

まだ質問された内容は解決していないと判断して書き込みます。

当方も、この現象が発生したので調査しました。

OS(Windows10 Pro)をクリーンインストールして、アプリを順次追加しながら確認しました。

厳密に特定(exe or dll)は出来ませんでしたが、どうもlogicool options plusのナニかがこの現象を起こしてるらしいと判りました。

質問者様もインストールしているのではないかと思います。（違っていたら別要因ですね）

logicool options plusをGeekでアンインストールして、従来ののlogicool optionsに戻してみたら良いと思います。当方はこれで再起動 or シャットダウンを妨げる"t"は発生しなくなりました。

もしかしたらlogicool options plusをインストールしただけでは無く、ログインしてバックアップをしないと発生しないかもです。

Answer (score 0):

ファイルの検索で探すんではなくて、タスクマネージャで、プロセスとかサービスで探してみよう